# prevent nvim unwanted TextChanged events in lua

Tags: lua, neovim

i use [vim-auto-save](https://github.com/907th/vim-auto-save) for vim and [autosave.nvim](https://github.com/0x00-ketsu/autosave.nvim) for neovim, i set both to save only in `InsertLeave` but in insert mode, when i press Enter within a pair of braces `{}, (), []`, to insert a newline, the plugin saves the file automatically, and i prevent this using: `autocmd TextChanged,TextChangedI <buffer> silent noautocmd` in my .vimrc and tried to apply the same to init.lua using vim.cmd: `vim.cmd("autocmd TextChanged,TextChangedI <buffer> silent noautocmd")` but this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I use this [plugin](https://github.com/pocco81/auto-save.nvim) for autosaving in nvim. This works well.
You can add these lines in your plugin config file for auto saving in normal mode and after text change event.

```lua
{
    enabled = true,
    execution_message = {
        message = function()
            return ("AutoSave: saved at " .. vim.fn.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        end,
        dim = 0.18, 
    },
    trigger_events = {"InsertLeave", "TextChanged"}, 
    condition = function(buf)
        local fn = vim.fn
        local utils = require("auto-save.utils.data")

        if
            fn.getbufvar(buf, "&modifiable") == 1 and
            utils.not_in(fn.getbufvar(buf, "&filetype"), {}) then
            return true
        end
        return false 
    end,
    write_all_buffers = false,  
    debounce_delay = 135,
    callbacks = { 
        enabling = nil, 
        disabling = nil,
        before_asserting_save = nil,
        before_saving = nil,
        after_saving = nil, 
    }
}
```

This is the default configuration of this plugin, consider configuring yourself as you want

Comment: I tried it with its default configurations as mentioned above, and the plugin still saves the file when I press enter inside any parentheses

Comment: `trigger_events = {"InsertLeave"}` this line in config defines that plugin will only save after leaving the insert mode, this means it won't save until unless you press `esc` in `insert mode`. If the plugin is saving after pressing enter in parentheses, this maybe cause of plugin conflicts. You should check the plugin conflicts, Also check which autopairs plugin you're using.

Comment: yes i know i set `trigger_events = {"InsertLeave"}` . i use [autoclose.nvim](https://github.com/m4xshen/autoclose.nvim) and i uninstalled it completely and the file still gets saved when pressing Enter within parentheses . am still searching and tried uninstalling multible other plugins